# Search and replace with regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace

In my string, I want to put a # in start and end of :  **cast(.* as varchar)**

I tried:

```
s.replaceAll("cast(.* as varchar)","#cast$1#");
```

But for a string **"('abas'  + cast(x as varchar ))"** the result is **"( ' abas ' +' # cast ( x as varchar # ' ) )"** which is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: be more clear. give your exact input and output vs what you would like it to output

Answer (score 2):

```
s.replaceAll("(cast\\(\\.\\* as varchar\\))","#$1#");
```

Will do the trick.

You were getting the wrong output because the parenthesis around "**.* as varchar**" weren't being scaped so the $1 was replacing what was inside them.

Comment: You also need to escape the '.' and '*' characters.

Comment: This time the result is "( ' abas ' +'#cast#' ( x as varchar ) )" which is still not correct

Comment: I also tried: s.replaceAll("cast(\\(.* as varchar.*\\))","#cast$1#")) , but still I get a wron answer: "('abas'  + #cast(x as varchar ))#"

Answer (score 0):

`()` have special meening, you need to escape:

```
s.replaceAll("(cast\\(.* as varchar\\))","#$1#");
```

Comment: the result is "( ' abas ' +'#cast#' ( x as varchar ) )" which is still not correct